# Java derby embedded DB error: The syntax of the string representation of a date/time value is incorrect

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, derby

I have the following problem using derby embedded DB in my application:

I changed a program that works with Mysql data base to use a Derby embedded data base because the client want it like this due to internet problems, everything works fine, but when i want to make a search using a range of dates the console shows the next error:

```
2018-12-10 17:26:18.920  INFO 107044 --- [nio-7009-exec-3] 

C.wDatos_ControlTransferencias_Servicios : /transferencias/consultar
2018-12-10 17:26:18.970  WARN 107044 --- [nio-7009-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 30000, SQLState: 22007
2018-12-10 17:26:18.970 ERROR 107044 --- [nio-7009-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The syntax of the string representation of a date/time value is incorrect.
2018-12-10 17:26:19.009 ERROR 107044 --- [nio-7009-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query] with root cause

org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: The syntax of the string representation of a date/time value is incorrect.
```

Like i said when it was working with MySql it works perfectly.

the query that i use is this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/transferencias/consultatodos", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestScope
    Collection<Transferencias> transferenciasConsultastodos(@RequestBody Consulta conf) throws JsonProcessingException {
        List<Transferencias> transl = new ArrayList<>();
        log.info("/transferencias/consultar");
        String Query = "Select trans from Transferencias trans";
        if (conf.getFecha1() != null && conf.getFecha2() != null) {
            Query = Query + " WHERE trans.fecha >= '" + conf.getFecha1() + "' AND trans.fecha<= '"+conf.getFecha2()+"'";
             if (conf.getBanco() != null) {
                Query = Query + " AND trans.banco = '" + conf.getBanco() +"'";
            }
             if (conf.getBeneficiario() != null) {
                Query = Query + " AND trans.beneficiario = '" + conf.getBeneficiario() +"'";
            }
             if (conf.getTipo() != null) {
                Query = Query + " AND trans.tipo = '" + conf.getTipo() +"'";
            }
        }
        else {
            if (conf.getBanco() != null) {
                Query = Query + " WHERE trans.banco = '" + conf.getBanco() +"'";
                if (conf.getBeneficiario() != null) {
                    Query = Query + " AND trans.beneficiario = '" + conf.getBeneficiario() +"'";
                }
                if (conf.getTipo() != null) {
                    Query = Query + " AND trans.tipo = '" + conf.getTipo() +"'";
                }
            }
            else {
                if (conf.getBeneficiario() != null) {
                    Query = Query + " WHERE trans.beneficiario = '" + conf.getBeneficiario() +"'";
                    if (conf.getTipo() != null) {
                        Query = Query + " AND trans.tipo = '" + conf.getTipo() +"'";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (conf.getTipo() != null) {
                        Query = Query + " WHERE trans.tipo = '" + conf.getTipo() +"'";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        transl = em.createQuery(Query).getResultList();
        return transl;
    }
```

When i do the search using other parameters it works perfectly, the problem is with the date.

The entity:

```
package ControlTransferencias.wDatos;



import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


/**
 *
 * @author juan.finol
 */
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Transferencias {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Long referencia;
    private String beneficiario;
    private String banco;
    private Date fecha;
    private String notaAdicional;
    private String descripcion;
    private Long monto;
    private String tipo;

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }
    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }
    public Long getReferencia() {
        return referencia;
    }
    public void setReferencia(Long referencia) {
        this.referencia = referencia;
    }
    public String getBeneficiario() {
        return beneficiario;
    }
    public void setBeneficiario(String beneficiario) {
        this.beneficiario = beneficiario;
    }
    public String getBanco() {
        return banco;
    }
    public void setBanco(String banco) {
        this.banco = banco;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }
    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }
    public Date getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }
    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }
    public Long getMonto() {
        return monto;
    }
    public void setMonto(Long monto) {
        this.monto = monto;
    }
    public String getNotaAdicional() {
        return notaAdicional;
    }
    public void setNotaAdicional(String notaAdicional) {
        this.notaAdicional = notaAdicional;
    }

}
```

Another thing that i notice was on the front end, when i make the search it shows the date like this: 1544414400000 and when i was using MySql it shows a dd-mm-yyyy format.

Note: the back end was made in spring boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there is no standardization of the default string format for date and time datatypes across database systems, so issuing SQL queries with dates in literal string format is quite non-portable.

A much more portable way is to use the JDBC `PreparedStatement` object, and its `setDate()` method, to get your date values into your query.

Using `PreparedStatement` and its parameter substitution features also has the excellent benefit of making your program much less susceptible to SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

Look here for excellent documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: After changing my code to use PreparedStatement and using Timestamp instead of Date the problem is solved, but i still have a problem in the front-end, when it shows me the date it does in a diferent format, for example the page shows "1548820800000" instead of "30-01-2019"

Answer (score 1):

@phantomsnake here is some code to format date's

```
   DateTimeFormatter mon = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM");
```

DateTimeFormatter day = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d");
   DateTimeFormatter year = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy");
   DateTimeFormatter dayOFwk = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE");
   DateTimeFormatter mdwd = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d EEEE");
   LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

```
System.out.println(mon.format(now));

System.out.println(day.format(now));

System.out.println(year.format(now));

System.out.println(dayOFwk.format(now));

System.out.println(mdwd.format(now));

}
```